# Assign formats/informats for Oracle dataset in SAS

Tags: oracle, format, sas, pass-through

I use SAS/ACCESS path-through facility in order to create a table in Oracle:

```
proc sql;
connect to oracle(user=mylogin orapw=mypw path=mypath);
execute (
          create table FCFCORE.RUS_FSC_RATE          
        ( DATE_KEY NUMBER(8),            
          RATE NUMBER(20,10),          
        )
) by oracle;
disconnect from oracle;
quit;
```

When in EG I check properties of the table I see that DATE_KEY has format/informat 9., and RATE has informat 22.10. How can I change these formats?

If I use proc datasets the following error occures: ERROR: The HEADER/VARIABLE UPDATE function is not supported by the ORACLE engine.

Comment: When you read data from Oracle into a SAS dataset, SAS decides what formats to attach to each variable.  How are you reading the data into SAS?  You might want to read up in SAS/access manual to see how SAS decides on a format to use.

Comment: Hello, Quentin! Sorry for my late reply (I was out of job and couldn't check the program). I use some standard autoexec macro in order to connect to Oracle DB. In this macro I found the following code for assigning library: `libname db_core oracle authdomain="Core" path=orcl;` But I did't find any format assignments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DBSASTYPE data step option to override the default.
Example:

```
proc append base=dblib.hrdata (dbsastype=(empid='CHAR(20)'))
            data=saslib.personnel;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks! I only wanted to show values in the other format. I think that the best solution for me will be usage of view with manually assigned formats.